# Create a nested data structure and fast accessing from another module while typing (Python)

Tags: python, nested, structure, namedtuple

Hello :) I'm using two modules in Python: Module 1 (for creating a nested data structure) and Module 2 (for accessing the "fields" of the structure and, very important, I want Python to show me the fields while I'm typing in Module 2 as there will be a lot of fields in Module 1). The nested structure is like that:

```
NAME A
    value: 5
    NAME B
        value:  6
        NAME B2
            Value:76
    NAME C
        Index: 78
```

I've been studying if using a list, a dictionary, a tuple... so far, I've seen named tuples may be the right solution because of immutability and using names for identifiers, instead of numbers. My code in Module 1 is:

```
from collections import namedtuple   
def ModbusDiction():

        NameA = namedtuple('NameA', ['value','NameB','NameC'])
        NameB = namedtuple('NameB', ['value','NameB2'])
        NameB2 = namedtuple('NameB2','value')
        NameC = namedtuple('NameC','index')
        NameC_value = NameC(78)
        NameB2_value = NameB2(76)
        NameB_value = NameB(6, NameB2_value)
        NameA_value = NameA(5,NameB_value,NameC_value)
        return NameA_value
```

My code in Module 2 (Files_CommonUse.folder_ModbusIndex.indexModbus is the path of module 1) is:

```
import Files_CommonUse.folder_ModbusIndex.indexModbus as index_modbus
indexmodbus = index_modbus.ModbusDiction()
print(indexmodbus.NameB.NameB2.value)
```

The resulf from the print is 76, so it's working. However, while I was typing *indexmodbus.*, the "field" *NameA* did not appear. While I was typing *indexmodbus.NameA.*, I would have liked to be shown *value*,*NameB* or *NameC*, but nothing was displayed. I wonder if this named tuple has become mutable. I'm using Eclipse, by the way.

Please, could anybody help me on this? :) Maybe the idea of named tuple does not work for my interest or I'm using the concept in a wrong way :S

Answer (score 0):

I would've used my custom class to create my custom data structure instead, because it's more flexible than `namedtuples`

```
def mod_bus_diction(**kwargs):
    return type('MyStructure', (), {**kwargs}) 


MyStructure = mod_bus_diction(
    value=5,
    NameB=mod_bus_diction(
        value=6,
        NameB2=mod_bus_diction(
            value=76
        )
    ),
    NameC=mod_bus_diction(
        index=78
    )
)
```

I checked it on `ipython` terminal it was suggesting the values and properties. I didn't check on eclipse by the way.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad! I'm trying your code. How do you call, for example NameB, in the module 2? I've realized your custom data structure is a nested dictionary with undefined arguments (**kwargs), right? 
 In module 2, I've tried 
indexmodbus2 = index_modbus.mod_bus_diction()
'''                 '''print(indexmodbus2["NameB"]) --> not subscriptable

Note: ''' ''' here is for separating instructions

Comment: @dmg No it's not a dictionary. It's a class. the function `mod_bus_diction` is a dynamic class creator. So you can simply instantiate from the class `indexmodbus = MyStructure()` and you have access to it's properties `print(indexmodbus.NameB.NameB2.value)` -> 76

Comment: Ah sorry, I missunderstood {**kargs}. Yeah, the result is working too but I don't know why Eclipse still does not display anything while I'm writing "indexmodbus." or "indexmodbus.NameB. ...". On which platform have you executed it?

Comment: @dmg I checked it on `ipython`

Answer (score 0):

As named tuples are a kind of light weight object, they behave like objects. That means, `NameA_value` is an instantiation of the `NameA` tuple object and if you return that instance from a function, the new variable becomes that instance. So your `indexmodbus` is an instance of the `NameA` tuple object. 
If you want to do: `indexmodbus.NameA`, you need another step above `NameA`, your function could then look like this:

```py
def ModbusDiction():

        TopTuple = namedtuple('top', ['NameA'])
        NameA = namedtuple('NameA', ['value','NameB','NameC'])
        NameB = namedtuple('NameB', ['value','NameB2'])
        NameB2 = namedtuple('NameB2','value')
        NameC = namedtuple('NameC','index')
        NameC_value = NameC(78)
        NameB2_value = NameB2(76)
        NameB_value = NameB(6, NameB2_value)
        NameA_value = NameA(5,NameB_value,NameC_value)
        TopTuple_value = TopTuple(NameA_value)
        return TopTuple_value
```

Now you can access `NameA` with: `indexmodbus.NameA` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but Eclipse is still not displaying them while typing :/

Comment: That is a problem with Eclipse then. You could work around that, by having your structure open in another window, or try @Mohammad Jafari 's suggestion. It could be, that named tuples are to new to be supported by Eclipses editor, but I can not confirm that.